# Где и как прописывать права доступа  chmod 666?

Tags: php

Где и как прописывать права доступа  chmod 666?

Answer (score 3):

Андрей Аршинов, не только в Linux а во всех Unix-подобных ОС

```
chmod ( string $filename , int $mode )

filename - путь к файлу
mode - восьмеричное значение
```

Т.е., должно быть так:

```
chmod("/dir/file", 0666);
```

Answer (score 0):

Права доступа используются только в Linux, команда `chmod('путь к файлу', 666);`

Answer (score 0):

Если по виндой - работаешь через FTP - то используй Total Commander - Вкладка Файлы->Изменить атрибуты